# Is there a MongoDB Trending Topics Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, trending

I have a group of documents in MongoDB with a "description" value about the size of a tweet.  I need to generate a trending topics list from this.  Clearly this is a solved problem but I can't find a definitive answer/gem for getting the job done without writing the code myself.

I am using ruby & mongoid in my app.

Is there any ruby gem that will help with or handle this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I know of no such gem, but here's an algorithm you may write for yourself:

1. Extract [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) from texts. Since texts are small (tweet size you said) extract all n-grams, no limit here.

   `"I eat icecream" => {(I), (eat), (icecream), (I eat), (eat icecream), (I eat icecream)}`
2. Compute [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) weight vectors for each text's n-grams

   `{(I):0.1, (eat):0.01, (icecream):0.2, (I eat):0.12, (eat icecream):0.001, (I eat icecream):0.00012}`
3. Use [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) as a measure function for a [incremental clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) algorithm over your vectors, maybe script the [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) library over [JRuby](http://jruby.org/)
4. Order all clusters by the population size. The n-grams in the centers of largest clusters are your trendy topics.

Answer (score 3):

A quick search of [rubygems.org](http://www.rubygems.org) revelead that you are going to have to do some programming. This is a good thing as a system to generically detect trends would either be hopelessly difficult to setup and tune or awful at guessing what dictates a "trend" in your application.

I'm going to make some assumptions about your application.

Let's assume users are self categorizing their tweets by using hash tags (#). Also, lets go ahead and say a sorted count of these hash tags would determine if a topic was trending.

Now let's talk about the computer science part. Given our assumptions above, you will need to be able to quickly query and sort a collection of hashtags to figure out what is trending.

Your are using MongoDB and mongoid (with rails) so the simplest way to do this would be to create a collection that has tag documents that contain a count of their use. Create indexes on tag and count.

When someone tweets, figure out what the hash tags are, look them up in the tags collection and increment their count. To figure out what is trending, query the tags collection and sort by count. This would get you all-time trending hash tags.

If you wanted to get more specific, instead of just storing counts, store counts broken out by time deltas (week, day, hour etc) perhaps storing them separately. You could create documents that represent your time delta instead of the individual tags and store all the tags with their counts inside.

```
{
    start: "start datetime",
    end: "end datetime",
    tags: {
        awesome: 3,
        cool: 2,
        boring: 2
    }
}
```

You could also use a capped collection. Hope that helps, all of this really depends on what you are trying to do. You can get really crazy and calculate the trends with time decay, etc. You could read the reddit or hacker news code to get a good idea of what that is like.